# Use react-feather icons in button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to use react-feather icons in React button but little bit confused.
My current code looks like this:

AppButton.js:

```
import React from 'react'

function AppButton({icon, text, onclick}) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="button" onClick={onclick}>
        {icon}
        <span>{text}</span>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default AppButton
```

App.js:

```
import AppButton from './component/AppButton'
import { Plus, Settings } from 'react-feather';

function App() {
  return (
    <main className="app">
      <div>
        <AppButton icon={<Settings size={20} />} text="Settings" onclick={()=>console.log("clicked")}/>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
export default App;
```

This code is working fine. However, I would like to render the button like this

> <AppButton icon="Settings" text="Settings" onclick={()=>console.log("clicked")}/>

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your wishes you need to import all İcons from react-feather then configure settings like that

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Icons from 'react-feather';

function AppButton({icon, text, onClick}) {
  const Icon = Icons[icon];
  
  return (
    <div className="button" onClick={onClick}>
      {Icon && <Icon size={20} />}
      <span>{text}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AppButton;
```

now you can use as **<AppButton icon="Settings" text="Settings" onClick={() => console.log("clicked")} />**